# Telephone hyperlink is not clickable in Gmail app on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, .net, iphone, asp.net-mvc

I am not able to click on telephone number hyperlink sent on Gmail app in iPhone.

Try to check with other hyperlinks but phone number hyperlink is not working.
Below is example.

```
<a href='tel:+911234567890' target="_blank">1234567890</a>
```

Comment: My suspicion is that this is an IOS change and that Gmail hasn't changed anything. The OS used to highlight phone numbers in many apps for me, but no longer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this problem appeared in 2020 and has still not been solved: https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/39339110/phone-number-is-no-longer-a-clickable-link-in-emails-on-gmail-for-ios?hl=en.

I think the technology behind this feature is patented by Apple, that's why it doesn't work for Gmail.

Comment: That's nonsense, it's [RFC 5341](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5341)